# Type annotating a class that is defined later (Forward Reference)

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

For style reasons I'm trying to keep definition of myDict before class Foo. This will cause a NameError because Foo is not yet defined.

```py
from typing import Dict

myDict: Dict[str, Foo] = {}

class Foo:
    pass
```

Moving myDict below Foo obviously fixes this, but is there any way I can keep myDict and its annotation up top?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can quote it as follows:

```
from typing import Dict

myDict: Dict[str, 'Foo'] = {}

class Foo:
    pass
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references for more information.

Answer (score 15):

Depending on which version on python (Py3.7+) you are running you can:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Then your code runs as is. [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#forward-references) introduced a delayed evaluation of annotations which means you don't need to use the original approach of putting the type in quotes, e.g. `'Foo'`.